# Solving linear exact first order differential of the form $Mdx + Ndy = f(x) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the D.E of the form $$Mdx + Ndy = f(x) $$. This is exact, and assume $\frac{\delta g(x,y)}{\delta x}=M $ and $\frac{\delta g(x,y)}{\delta y}=N$

TRIAL:

I think that the implicit general solution becomes
$$g(x,y)=\int f(x)dx + c$$
Because, $$Mdx + Ndy= dg(x,y)=f(x)$$and thus:$g(x,y)=\int f(x)dx + c$

Question:

1.Is this method correct? If it is not, what is the correct solution?

2. How do we approach this solution if it is non-exact?

Comment: @Score : your method is correct if $Mdx+Ndy$ is a total differential, that is if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$. If not, what you did is false. In that case you have to find an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ so that  $\mu Mdx+\mu Ndy$ be a total differential of a function $F=\mu f$